# DSL for date manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, dsl

I have an existing asp.net (c#) application. I need to provide users with a way to create flexibles rules to calculate an effective date given a hiredate and an enrollmentdate.

Some examples of rules that might be used:

1. The later of hiredate or enrollmentdate
2. HireDate + 90 Days
3. The first of the Month after the enrollment date
4. If the enrollment date is before the 15 of the month, then the effective date is the 1st of the next month. If it is on the 15 or after, it's the 1st of the month after that.

I started out with a handful of offset fields (day offset, month offset, etc...), but as I come across new requirements, I'm coming to realize the current approach isn't flexible enough.

What I would like to do is allow the end user to define a function that returns a date given two parameters (hiredate, enrollmentdate), and store that function in the database. When I need to calculate the effectivedate I'd pull this function out of the database execute it passing in the parameters to get my effectivedate.

What I would need (I think) is a Domain Specific Language (DSL) that would allow the creation of this function. It's syntax would have to allow easy manipulation of dates.

I'm looking for recommendations on DSLs that fit my requirement. If my DSL strategy is off base, please recommend another path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently implenting my solution using the [flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/) expression parser. This allows me to use most of the methods and properties that the .NET DateTime struct affords me. I was pointed in this direction by re-posting my question as seen below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14730487/21155

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a DSL like this (and I've spent a lot of time looking at related topics).

Allowing users to specify date/time expressions is a *very* hard problem.  My own [Natural Language Engine](http://nlp.abodit.com) might be a suitable starting point or a good place to get some ideas.

In that engine I have a concept of a `TemporalExpression`.  The NLP engine can parse strings as complex as *'last year on a friday after 5pm in May'* and create an accurate expression tree for that.  If you pull down the various `Abodit` packages off Nuget you can explore the classes and methods around this idea.  There are also classes for units of measure including time intervals that might help (`TimeSpan` for example can't handle "1 month and 2 days").

You can extend the engine to parse your own tokens (both simple like 'hire date' or complex, like recognizing a given holiday by name to create a new `TemporalExpression`).

You might also want to look at DAML and [OWL-Time](http://www.isi.edu/~hobbs/time/owl-time-july04.txt) for ideas around representing temporal expressions in the Semantic Web.

*Disclaimer: I wrote it, this is a link to my site, it's still a work in progress, there's a new version coming soon with 'production rules' and much improved performance, happy to discuss offline, blah blah...*

Comment: Not really relevant to the DSL side of things, but I'd be interested to hear if my Noda Time project (http://noda-time.googlecode.com) would integrate nicely with this. It's got a much richer data model than .NET's (which isn't saying much) - if you're able to let us handle the date/time part, and you focus on the natural language part, that could be interesting. Feel free to drop a mail to project mailing list if this is something you'd be interested in...

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll contact you there to discuss.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for using CSharpCodeProvider? Can I enforce a method signature? And prevent the user from executing code with side effects?

Comment: @Aheho, That might be one approach: use C# instead of a DSL, you might want to create a *new question* on SO and perhaps include the tag `Roslyn` to get more input on that idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730219/using-csharpcodeprovider-to-allow-user-created-functions